# Making slider image fade out

Tags: jssor

I have a slider that fades images.

The transition works, the new image fades it, but the previous image doesn't fade out.

The previous image simply disappears after the next image has fully faded in.

For opaque images this of course is perfectly fine as we don't need to the previous image fade out. It's simply overlaid by the new image.

The problem is that my images have transparent regions, so it would be necessary that the previous image fades out.

How could I achieve this?

My current code is this:

```
   jssor_1_slider_init = function() {

        var jssor_1_SlideshowTransitions = [
          {$Duration:800,$Opacity:2}
        ];

        var jssor_1_options = {
          $AutoPlay: 1,
          $LazyLoading: 1,
          $SlideshowOptions: {
            $Class: $JssorSlideshowRunner$,
            $Transitions: jssor_1_SlideshowTransitions
          }
        };

        var jssor_1_slider = new $JssorSlider$("jssor_1", jssor_1_options);

        /*#region responsive code begin*/

        var MAX_WIDTH = 256;

        function ScaleSlider() {
            var containerElement = jssor_1_slider.$Elmt.parentNode;
            var containerWidth = containerElement.clientWidth;

            if (containerWidth) {

                var expectedWidth = Math.min(MAX_WIDTH || containerWidth, containerWidth);

                jssor_1_slider.$ScaleWidth(expectedWidth);
            }
            else {
                window.setTimeout(ScaleSlider, 30);
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Given image with transparent area, to make jssor slider with slideshow, you can use twins transitions.

Open options window, choose one or more twins slideshow transitions.

Answer (score 0):

Followed by documentation and examples on [this page](https://www.jssor.com/slideshow/x-twins.html)
 I think you need this `{$Duration:700,$Opacity:2,$Brother:{$Duration:700,$Opacity:2}}`

Example : Fade Twins